# Unable to selectively update column value

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an sqlite database of movies with a `BookMarked` column where the value `1` denotes  a movie has been book marked, and `0` denotes it has not. All default values are `0`.

```
ID| BookMarked
--+--------
1 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 1  <--- movie is BookMarked
```

I have created a method to update individual `BookMarked` column values based on a respective `ID` value

```
public void bookMark(String ID){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    String value = "1";
    String strFilter = "ID="+ID;

    newValues.put("BookMarked", value);

    db.update("Movies", newValues, strFilter, null);

}
```

So for example, bookMark(1) should change the above table to

```
ID| BookMarked
--+--------
1 | 1  <--- movie is BookMarked
2 | 0
3 | 1  <--- movie is BookMarked
```

The problem is I cannot selectivly change an individual column value in the `BookMarked` despite my syntax looking correct to me.

I can change the line

> db.update("Movies", newValues, strFilter, null);

to this by removing the filter and setting the argument to null

> db.update("Movies", newValues, null, null);

and I get this when I called bookMark()

```
ID| BookMarked
--+--------
1 | 1  
2 | 1
3 | 1
```

Why doesn't the filter work?

**edit:**

I am dumping the cursor to test the code

```
public void bookMark(String ID) {

        // Updating the column

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        String value = "1";
        String strFilter = "ID="+ID;
        newValues.put("BookMarked", value);
        db.update("Movies", newValues, strFilter, null);


        // Dumping the cursor 

        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables("Movies");
        String[] sqlSelect = new String[]{"BookMarked"};
        String[] selectionArg = new String[]{value};
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, "BookMarked=?", selectionArg, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        Log.v("TAG","Dumping....");
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);

        }
```

Comment: Obviously, your `ID` value does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to update the db you need

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

so you can change it.

Then the `update` should be

```
db.update("Movies", newValues, "ID=?", new String[] { ID });
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. This line `db.update("Movies", newValues, null, null);` update ALL values, and this line `db.update("Movies", newValues, strFilter, null);` updates NO values